# Using VBA to select a cell with text in it

Tags: vba, excel

How do I select a cell with "Part # 1" in it, and then use that cell as one of the parameters to select a range of cells. For example: If "Part # 1" was in cell A1, I want to select a range of cells A1:D4.

```
Sub Part_1_Select

'Seach for Cell somehow'
Cell.Activate
ActiveCell: D4.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

This is what I'm thinking it should be similar too.

Comment: Is this the same problem as your [superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/941465/is-it-possible-to-reference-two-cells-in-excel-to-find-a-third-cell)?

Comment: Indirectly. I have two different possible solutions. My superuser post is about the first, this is about the second.

Comment: Where's the part of your code that finds the string you're looking for?

Comment: The part that finds the cell that "Part # 1" is in? Its not there because that's the part I don't know how to do.

Comment: Will "Part # 1" only appear once on the sheet?

Comment: Yes @padawan0007 it will only appear once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Range(Cells.Find(What:="Part # 1").Address & ":D4").Select
```

Comment: I believe you are right padawan0007. So if @bdkong combines both answers, it should solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
    If c.Value = "Part # 1" Then
       Cell.Activate
       Range(c & ":D4").Select
    End If
Next
```

This isn't perfect code but it may provide you with a good starting point to get where you want.

Comment: Gave me a '"Range' of Object'_Global' failed".

Comment: Fourth.     Range(c & ":D4").Select

Comment: I think that line would need to be `Range(c.Address & ":D4").Select`